# Can't install racc gem on Amazon Linux EC2 instance

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

I created an instance of EC2 and am attempting to install the `racc` gem (attempting to install the `selenium-webdriver` gem, which depends on `racc`).  I get this error while running `gem install racc`:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing racc:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/ec2-user/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/racc-1.6.0/ext/racc/cparse
/usr/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rubygems -r ./siteconf20221017-6091-l0he2f.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_block_call()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:471:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:564:in `try_link0'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:582:in `try_link'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:794:in `try_func'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1083:in `block in have_func'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:971:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:970:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1082:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/ec2-user/.local/share/gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/racc-1.6.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.local/share/gem/ruby/gems/racc-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.local/share/gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/racc-1.6.0/gem_make.out
```

I found an article that said I needed to perform a full ruby installation by running `sudo yum install ruby-devel`, but that did not fix the problem.

In case it's needed by anyone, here is the contents of `/home/ec2-user/.local/share/gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/racc-1.6.0/mkmf.log`:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/usr/include -I.    -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -mtune=generic -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-as-needed  -m64   -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed `racc` because `nokogiri` depends on it, but since `nokogiri` doesn't specify what version of `racc` it needs, bundler will try to get the latest version.  Ruby 3.x includes `racc` 1.5.2, so I only needed to include `gem 'racc', '1.5.2'` in my Gemfile to fix the issue.